# Why doesn't my function that accepts an `std::string` to sort change it?

Tags: c++, string, sorting, pass-by-reference

I have a project and I want to ask for some things. How can I make a string with descending order using `cin<<word;`? I tried this from a website that I found but it doesn't work with cin. Here is the code:

```
void descOrder(string s) 
{ 
    sort(s.begin(), s.end(), greater<char>()); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    string s = "geeksforgeeks"; 
    descOrder(s); // function call 
    return 0; 
}
```

To be more clear I want to do this

- Input: `geek for geeks`
- Output `ssrokkggfeeee`

Also, how can I replace letters from a string using the alphabet, for instance, the Hello I want to be like this H to be I, e to be f, l to be m, o to be p, and if a word contains the letter z I want to replace with the letter a.

The final question I want to print from a string first the according and after the vowels

Comment: please write descriptive titles so that others can search

Answer (score 2):

You are passing your `std::string` by value, hence `desOrder()` gets a copy from it and then sorts it and you get nothing.

Pass your `std::string` by reference to be able to change it not a copy from it.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void descOrder(std::string & s)
{
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), std::greater<char>());
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "geeksforgeeks";
    descOrder(s); // function call
    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Plz, post one question per post and see this [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Another solution would be to return the sorted string (by value) from descOrder: std::string descOrder(std::string s) { std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), std::greater<char>()); return s; } .. in main: int main() { auto s = descOrder("geeksforgeeks"); std::cout << s; return 0; } - this way you have a function with a clean return.

Comment: @Wolfgang I want to correct something misunderstood by the OP and didn't want to change the OP's structure.

Comment: I understand and welcome this, which is why I had inserted my comment only as a comment and not as an alternative answer. Nevertheless, I hoped to show the OP that there are other reasonable approaches.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods applicable:

**1. Pass value by reference:**

When you pass a variable by reference, it does manipulates the original variable's value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void descOrder(std::string & s) // just use an '&' sign here
{ 
    sort(s.begin(), s.end(), std::greater<char>()); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    std::string s = "geeksforgeeks";

    descOrder(s); // function call

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

**2. Return value instead of passing by reference:**

If you don't want to change the original value but want to store in another variable or directly print it, you may do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::string descOrder(std::string s) 
{ 
    sort(s.begin(), s.end(), std::greater<char>());
    return s;
} 

int main() 
{ 
    std::string s = "geeksforgeeks";

    std::string changedS = descOrder(s); // function call AND assigning to another variable

    std::cout << changedS << std::endl;

    // alternatively (uncomment)...
    // std::cout << descOrder(s) << std::endl; // if you just want to print

    return 0; 
}
```